# Easy way to re-subscribe on Tag

Tags: discussion, tags, email, email-notification, subscription

Last 3 months ago , I had un-subscribe on some tags. Today, I want to subscribe on them again. 
So , I find subscription confirm message from my old mails and clicked on **Confirm Subscription** links.
But I had failed to subscribe on them and these links lead me to a page of **Subscription not found** Page.
 Here is [sample link](https://stackexchange.com/filters/email-confirm/99999999).

> 

**Subscription not found

Your subscription could not be found. Did you click a link in an old email?**

Yes .. sure ! I had clicked on old email.

If so I need to find these [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) and try to subscribe them. Has there any easy ways to get it ?
Because I am boring to do so and links didn't give any helps for me.

Comment: Confirm emails usually expire, by design. There's no point to confirm something you did 10 years ago. Just hover the tag and click "subscribe" again. Much easier than digging for old emails.

Comment: @ShadowWizard :P If so , what would I do now ? Woooh...! I expect to add some buttons or links on 404 page to re-subscribe my tags again on each page ;)

Comment: Too minor in my opinion. :-)